# How to sort QtableWiget for particular row range in QT

Tags: qt

I want to sort Qtable widget by column but first row should not be considered while sorting( means sorting should be done from 2nd row onwards)
Is there any way to use sortbycloumn() method of Qtable Widgetfor particular row range or is there any other way in *QT* to sort QTableWidget from 2nd row onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something along these lines:

- Subclass QTableWidgetItem
- Re-implement the < operator
- Set a special flag on all of the items in the first row (using setData())

Then you can do something like this:

```
bool MyTableWidget::operator <(MyTableWidgetItem *other)
{
  if( specialFlag )
    return true;

  return QTableWidgetItem::operator<(other);
}
```

This way your first row is still being sorted, but you've forced it to always be considered "less" than every other.

In order to keep your row from going to the bottom when you change sorting directions (ascending vs descending), you can change the behavior of the < function by grabbing the header view from your table widget and asking it which direction your sorting.

See:

- QTableWidgetItem::tableWidget()
- QTableWidget::headerView()
- QHeaderView::sortIndicatorOrder()